# Deserializing multiple JSON result with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to deserialize sample JSON at the end of this question with below. But results.count is always 0.
how can i deserialize this JSON with multiple data so i can loop with

```
foreach (Foo r in results)
{
   Response.Write(r.html);
}

[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{
public string html { get; set; }
public string bannerid { get; set; }
public string contenttype { get; set; }
public string alt { get; set; }
public string width { get; set; }
public string height { get; set; }
public string url { get; set; }
public string bannertext { get; set; }
public string bannerurl { get; set; }
public string campaignid { get; set; }
public string version { get; set; }
public string cpc { get; set; }
}

public List<Foo> GetFooMultiple(string publisherOrSiteId)
{
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Foo> results = ser.Deserialize<List<Foo>>(json);
        return results;        
}

List<Foo> results = GetFooMultiple("11111,22222");
Response.Write(results.Count);
```

Json string:

```
"{ "11111" : { "alt" : "none",
  "bannerid" : "21655",
  "bannertext" : "Sample 1",
  "bannerurl" : "http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "campaignid" : "1216",
  "contenttype" : "png",
  "cpc" : "0.00060",
  "height" : 50,
  "html" : "<a href='http://foo.com/foo.png'><img src='http://foo.com/foo.png' width='320' height='50' alt='foo' /></a>",
  "url" : "http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "version" : "1",
  "width" : 320
},
  "22222" : { "alt" : "",
  "bannerid" : "21937",
  "bannertext" : "Sample 2",
  "bannerurl" : "",
  "campaignid" : "1241",
  "contenttype" : "txt",
  "cpc" : "0.00060",
  "height" : 0,
  "html" : "<a href='http://foo.com/foo.pngD'>Sample 2</a>",
  "url" : "http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "version" : "1",
  "width" : 0
}
}"
```

The JSON as a C# string, for MVCE:

```
    string json = @"{ ""11111"" : {
        ""alt"" : ""none"",
  ""bannerid"" : ""21655"",
  ""bannertext"" : ""Sample 1"",
  ""bannerurl"" : ""http://foo.com/foo.png"",
  ""campaignid"" : ""1216"",
  ""contenttype"" : ""png"",
  ""cpc"" : ""0.00060"",
  ""height"" : 50,
  ""html"" : ""<a href='http://foo.com/foo.png'><img src='http://foo.com/foo.png' width='320' height='50' alt='foo' /></a>"",
        ""url"" : ""http://foo.com/foo.png"",
        ""version"" : ""1"",
  ""width"" : 320
},
  ""22222"" : {
        ""alt"" : """",
  ""bannerid"" : ""21937"",
  ""bannertext"" : ""Sample 2"",
  ""bannerurl"" : """",
  ""campaignid"" : ""1241"",
  ""contenttype"" : ""txt"",
  ""cpc"" : ""0.00060"",
  ""height"" : 0,
  ""html"" : ""<a href='http://foo.com/foo.pngD'>Sample 2</a>"",
  ""url"" : ""http://foo.com/foo.png"",
  ""version"" : ""1"",
  ""width"" : 0
}
}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) supports this type of structures. So you could do this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, Foo>>(json);
```

and then:

```
var foo1 = result["11111"];
var foo2 = result["22222"];
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it with .net's built in libraries?

Comment: @nLL, nope. JavaScriptSerializer doesn't support such JSON format. The best you could get is `serializer.DeserializeObject(json)` which returns dictionary of non strongly typed objects.

Comment: bugger :) I know have to include a binary for just couple of lines!

Answer (score 0):

What is `publisherOrSiteId` parameter for and what are "11111" and "22222" doing in your json string? Correct JSON would be

```
"[{ "alt" : "none",
  "bannerid" : "21655",
  "bannertext" : "Sample 1",
  "bannerurl" : "http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "campaignid" : "1216",
  "contenttype" : "png",
  "cpc" : "0.00060",
  "height" : 50,
  "html" : "<a href='"http://foo.com/foo.png'><img src='"http://foo.com/foo.png' width='320' height='50' alt='foo' /></a>",
  "url" : ""http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "version" : "1",
  "width" : 320
},
   { "alt" : "",
  "bannerid" : "21937",
  "bannertext" : "Sample 2",
  "bannerurl" : "",
  "campaignid" : "1241",
  "contenttype" : "txt",
  "cpc" : "0.00060",
  "height" : 0,
  "html" : "<a href='http://foo.com/foo.pngD'>Sample 2</a>",
  "url" : "http://foo.com/foo.png",
  "version" : "1",
  "width" : 0
}]"
```

Comment: you JSON string itself is well formated JSON-string. But it cannot be deserialized into List of Foo objects. If you want to deserialize into `List<Foo>`, you should use JSON content i adviced

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ. `JavaScriptSerializer` can deserialize a `Dictionary<string, Foo>`:

```
var results = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Foo>>(json); // json now defined in question
var foo1 = results["11111"];
Console.WriteLine(results["11111"].bannerid); // 21655 expected
```

Output

> 21655